# Excel VBA using loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, spreadsheet

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()


Dim EmptyRow As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim newDate As Date


 Set MyRange = Worksheets("Submissions").Range("A:A")
 EmptyRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyRange) + 1

 Set MyRange2 = Worksheets("DateLoop").Range("A:A")
 EmptyRow2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyRange2) + 1

 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 1).Value = txtFirstName.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 2).Value = txtLastName.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 3).Value = txtNumGuests.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 4).Value = txtPhone.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 5).Value = txtEmail.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 6).Value = tbstdate.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 7).Value = tbenddate.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 8).Value = txtNumDays.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 9).Value = txtPriceNight.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 10).Value = txtEnvFee.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 11).Value = txtEntFee.Value
 Sheets("Submissions").Cells(EmptyRow, 12).Value = txtTotal.Value

Unload Me

For i = 0 To txtNumDays.Value

conDate = CDate(tbstdate.Value)
Sheets("DateLoop").Cells(EmptyRow2, 1).Value = conDate + i
Sheets("DateLoop").Cells(EmptyRow2, 2).Value = txtNumGuests.Value

Next i


End Sub
```

What I want to be able to do is use the loop at the bottom to show all the dates that would be a part of the loop.

Example: for a reservation from 12/17/14-12/22/14 for 4 guests, it will only insert 12/22/14 with 4 guests into the sheet. I need it to be able to list out each date (all 6 of them) on a new row even though the guests will remain the same each time. The purpose is to keep track of how many people are scheduled for each day of the year which is why I need everyday listed out

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: It would help if you can clarify the requirements and visualize the desired result by showing sample data in Excel Worksheet. Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want each date then you'll need to update the value of EmptyRow2 in the FOR loop. currently it updates it for everyday but  then overwrites it and it will end with the value conDate + txtNumDays.Value. Add in before the "Next i" line:

```
EmptyRow2 = EmptyRow2 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is replacing the contents of `Sheets("DateLoop").Cells(EmptyRow2, 1)` and `Sheets("DateLoop").Cells(EmptyRow2, 2)` with each loop. If you want a new row for each date, change the loop to the following:

```
For i = 0 To txtNumDays.Value

conDate = CDate(tbstdate.Value)
Sheets("DateLoop").Cells(EmptyRow2 + i, 1).Value = conDate + i
Sheets("DateLoop").Cells(EmptyRow2 + i, 2).Value = txtNumGuests.Value

Next i
```

Comment: Nicely added Engineer, much cleaner method than mine!